# HttpGet returns 406 error after setting Accept header

Tags: httprequest, zip, http-status-code-406, http-accept-header

I have a url with ending &filename=xxxx after hitting it through browser, it redirects to some XXX url start downloading the expected zip file.

When I try to hit the same url through Java code, it reutrns 406 Not Acceptable. 
After search in internet, I have tried following attempts

`HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL).addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip");
request.addHeader("Accept", String.valueOf(ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM))`

When I tried to change in the execute method itself,
 `httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(httpUrl), httpClientContext)`
HttpGet object not converted to HttpUriRequest and returns Hostname as null error.

Comment: even without setting Accept Header, ContentType received 406 Response.